# Cannot permute invalid or irregular data

Tags: ads

I am trying to run a simple simulation for an NFC (Near Field Communication) system using a mutual inductor component to connect two coils. I have written a simple formula for the coupling factor `k` (\$k\$), of which distance `dist` (\$\mathrm{dist}\$) is a variable.

`k = u0*n1*n2*pi*d1*d1*d2*d2/(2*sqrt((Lread*Ltag)*((dist*dist)+(d2*d2))**3))`

i.e.
$$
k = \frac{u_0\cdot n_1\cdot n_2\cdot\pi\cdot d_1^2\cdot d_2^2}{2\sqrt{L_\mathrm{read}\cdot L_\mathrm{tag}\cdot(\mathrm{dist}^2+d_2^2)^3}}
$$
Now, my problem is that when I simulate the system (Transient) and applly `dist` as a swept variable, I see that from the Data Display Window that the number of points for `dist` is 'irregular'.

As a result of this, I cannot do a `plot_vs()` function.  For example, I cannot plot `plot_vs(Uout,dist)`.

I am not very familiar with Advanced Design System, and so I need some help on what I might be doing wrong.
[image: Error Message on Attribute Properties]

I'll appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: What are `Lread` and `Uload` and how are they calculated? Do you need to do a transient simulation, or could you get the result you want from an AC simulation?

Comment: `Lread` is the 'reader' inductance in Henry. It is has a hardcoded value. The `Uload` is a named node for the load voltage. Since I am simulating an NFC system, i think Transient will be more appropriate, because it is time-based.

Comment: What happens if you just plot `Uload` on the y axis? Normally if you do a sweep, ADS will automatically plot a family of curves without any change to the graph setup.

Comment: If I do it that way, time is going to be on the x-axis. I will get a plot of `Uload` against time at different values of the swept variable (`dist`), which is not what I am trying to achieve. The thing is that I want `dist` on the x-axis. I want a plot of `Uload` against `dist`. Thanks for your response so far!

Comment: `Uload` at some particular instant in time? Or a family of 100,000 curves giving `Uload` vs `dist` at each moment in the transient simulation? The issue is probably that the transient simulation uses adaptive time stepping, so the simulation for each value of `dist` doesn't have points at the exact same time instants.

Comment: You're absolutely right in saying that the transient simulation uses adaptive time stepping. Is there then a way to keep the time constant and plot against different values of `dist`?

Comment: I might have figured out the solution! Run the transient simulation over just 1time step. Thanks for helping me with the insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I need to set the transient simulation to have just 1 time step. Done!